# Android - Main.xml doesn't recognize my color values...?

Tags: android, eclipse, program-entry-point

In the values/colors.xml, I put:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<color name="blank">#f0f0f0</color>
</resources>
```

In the layout/main.xml, I put:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textColor="@colors/blank"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I got the error:

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value '@colors/blank')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's @color/blank, not @colors/blank. There's no 's' :)